# Possible data leakage or overfitting?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm working on a multi-class classification problem. The data is of the form

```
Feature1 Feature2 Feature3  Features4 feature5 features features Class
 0.1       0.2      0.3       1         0.2      0.9       0.5   Apple
 0.3       0.1      0.4        0.2     0.2       1.1       1.9    Orange
 0.12       0.22    0.13       1.4     1.5       1.9       1      Banana
 0.112      0.231   0.3        8        4         4        2      Watermelon
```

My dataset has 7 features and 42000 rows. Around 22000 of them belong to the class Apple and the rest equally divided amongst others. Now I have fit using the random forest classifier.

Comment: Things that are not correct. 1) standardizing  `X_train` and then do cross-validation: you have to estimate mean and sd from the training set only and then use them to scale both training and validation test. 2) you are applying SMOTE on the entire `X_train` and then running cross-validation: you are using information from the validation set to augment the training data. You need to apply SMOTE on the only training set of each round of the cross-validation. 3) Performances must be evaluated only on the validation test, not the oversampled validation set.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out these issues. I've tried implementing using pipeline which would solve this issue. However, pipeline and SMOTE doesn't seem to work with each other as it throws many errors. Can you please show me an example to implement the changes you've suggested. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try visualizing to see if any of the features are important . Exploring the data is always helpful or use. Try this

```
feature_importance = classifier.feature_importances_
feature_importance = 100.0 * (feature_importance / feature_importance.max())
sorted_idx = np.argsort(feature_importance)
pos = np.arange(sorted_idx.shape[0]) + .5

plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
plt.barh(pos, feature_importance[sorted_idx], align='center')
plt.yticks(pos, X_train.columns[sorted_idx]) #X_train is your training dataset
plt.xlabel('Relative Importance')
plt.title('Variable Importance')
plt.show()
```

Comment: After performing feature selection, I'm still getting the same accuracy of 98%

Comment: the code I have given should give you a graph. that represents importance of features that should let you know if there is a data leakage or overfitting

Comment: From the graph, I've selected a subset of features and fit the model and still got the same accuracy scores. I was confused about why they are still the same?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should keep your test data intact - over sample only your train data :
So, remove the line `X_test,y_test = oversample.fit_resample(X_test,y_test)`.

Also, you are printing the score for your train data here : `print(np.mean(cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, cv=10)))` - what happens when you try and print it for your test data?

Plus, you should probably increase `min_samples_leaf` from 1 to a higher value - 1 here means you are allowing a split even though there is only data point there - that can certainly help you overfit.

Comment: With your suggestion, I've removed the oversample.fit for test data and also removed the min_samples_leaf option. With these changes, I'm getting a 98% accuracy for training and 95% for test data.

Comment: Well, your train and valid accuracy seem to line up then! Try out with another random state and see if you are getting similar values - that would give you more confidence in the metric!

Comment: Tried with multiple random states and getting similar values. Thanks for the suggestions!.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of aspects that are wrong.

`X_train,y_train = oversample.fit_resample(X_train,y_train)`

You cannot do that before the cross-validation. You are using information from the validation set to oversample the training set.

`X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)`

You cannot scale the entire dataset and then run cross-validation. You are using the samples that will go into the validation set (of each round of the CV) to estimate mean and sd. That's not correct.

A way to implement it is:

```
kf = KFold(n_splits=10)
acc = np.zeros(10)
k=0
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X_train):

  X_tr = X_train[train_index, :]
  y_tr = y_train[train_index]

  X_te = X_test[test_index, :]
  y_te = y_train[test_index]

  scaler = StandardScaler()
  X_tr = scaler.fit_transform(X_tr)
  X_te = scaler.transform(X_te)
  
  oversample = SMOTE()
  X_tr,y_tr = oversample.fit_resample(X_tr,y_tr)
    
  classifier = RandomForestClassifier(
    n_estimators=100,
    criterion='gini',
    max_depth=22,
    min_samples_split=2,
    min_samples_leaf=1,
    min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
    max_features='auto',
    max_leaf_nodes=None,
    min_impurity_decrease=0.0,
    min_impurity_split=None,
    bootstrap=True,
    oob_score=False,
    n_jobs=-1,
    random_state=0,
    verbose=0,
    warm_start=False,
    class_weight='balanced'
  )

  classifier.fit(X_tr, y_tr)
  y_pr = classifier.predict(X_te)

  acc[k] = np.sum(y_te == y_pr) / len(y_te)
  k+=1

np.mean(acc)
```